# Existence and uniqueness of ODE when the function is bounded by other functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=f\left(t,x\right)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I also found that $g_1\left(t,x\right)\leq f\left(t,x\right)\leq g_2\left(t,x\right)$ for two continuous functions $g_1$ and $g_2$. Furthermore, I know that the solutions to the ODEs $\frac{dy_i}{dt}=g_i\left(t,y_i\right)$, $y_i\left(t_0\right)=x_0$ ($i=1,2$) exist and are unique for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Is this enough to conclude that the solution to my original ODE exists and is unique for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not sufficient. For example, consider the differential equation $x'=f(t,x)$ with $f(t,x)=\sqrt x$ in a neighborhood of zero, but with $f$ bounded, say $|f|\le M$. Then you can take $g_1(t,x)=-M$ and $g_2(t,x)=M$. The last two give rise to unique solutions but still $x'=f(t,x)$ has nonunique solutions for $x(0)=0$.